# mysql, issues finding this scientific value in database

Tags: mysql

I have stored this value into a column in mysql "1e-06" (stored in float type)

When I do a search for this value with "0.000001", I get no matches. Any ideas?

```
SELECT *
FROM `MATCH__DESTINATION`
WHERE `W_m` = 0.000001
```

Answer (score 0):

From this [mailing list thread](http://markmail.org/message/tdnnussusahovcf7):

> > MySQL don't detect the equal float numbers if aren't in[t]eger, left
> >
> > float alwa[y]s greater then right float es. 1.1 > 1.1 = true.
> >
> > `mysql> SELECT * FROM float_bug WHERE f=1.1; Empty set (0.00 sec)`
>
> It's an inexactness of floating point arithmetic. Use `DECIMAL` type
>   instead.

Answer (score 0):

try to limit the matching column and value to equal decimal precision and then compare.

```
SELECT *
FROM `MATCH__DESTINATION`
WHERE Cast(`W_m` as Decimal(6,6)) = Cast(0.000001 as Decimal(6,6))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no issues in what you are doing. The only reason the SELECT does not return any results is because there are no matches. A couple of things:

1. Does the column `W_m` allows floating values upto 6 decimal places?
2. Are you sure that such a value actually exist in your table? Can you try fetching the same record, that has `W_m` as 1e-06, using any other WHERE predicates? If not, is it possible to do a `SELECT *` with no WHERE condition and then manually check if that record actually exists?